# Spring Data JPA Error on One to Many join table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Having a hard time getting this to work.

I have three entities.
User / Organization / Membership

Membership is a join table entity using a compound ID from userId and organizationId.... How do I save to this table using Spring JPA to show this relationship?

Currently I am getting this error
`Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [java.lang.Integer] :` com.reeftrader.Hades.OrganizationMembership.OrganizationMembershipId.organizationId` (setter)] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "o" is null`

User entity

```
package com.reeftrader.Hades.user;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(
            name = "user_id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private int userId;
    @Column(
            name = "first_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "varchar(100)"
    )

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<OrganizationMembership> membership;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_identity",
            joinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "identity_id", referencedColumnName = "identity_id") })
    private Identity identity;
```

Organization entity

```
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(
            name = "organization_id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private int organizationId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<OrganizationMembership> membership;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "organization_identity",
            joinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "identity_id", referencedColumnName = "identity_id") })
    private Identity identity;
}
```

Membership entity

```
public class OrganizationMembership {

    @EmbeddedId
    OrganizationMembershipId organizationMembershipId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("organization_id")//Name comes from OrganizationMembershipId attribute
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
    private Organization organization;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("user_id")//Name comes from OrganizationMembershipId attribute
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "membership_role")
    @NonNull
    private MembershipRole membershipRole;
}
```

OrganizationMembershipID

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class OrganizationMembershipId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "organization_id")
    private int organizationId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
}
```

Service method to save(work in progress want to use hibernate persistence for the Identity save and membership save after creating an organization

```
public Organization create(OrganizationRequest request) {
        List<OrganizationMembership> membershipList = new ArrayList<>();
        Organization organization = Organization.builder()
                .organizationName(request.getOrganizationName())
                .details(request.getDetails())
                .establishedDate(request.getEstablishedDate())
                .organizationType(request.getOrganizationType())
                .membership(membershipList)
                .build();

        // build user to add to membership
        User user = User.builder()
                .userId(request.getUserId())
                .build();

        OrganizationMembership membership = OrganizationMembership.builder()
                .user(user)
                .organization(organization)
                .membershipRole(MembershipRole.OWNER)
                .build();
        organization.getMembership().add(membership);
        organizationRepository.save(organization);

        // Create new identity for Organization
        Identity identity = Identity.builder()
                .organizationId(organization.getOrganizationId())
                .identityType(IdentityType.ORGANIZATION)
                .build();
        identityRepository.save(identity);

        return organization;
    }
```

Identity Repository

```
package com.reeftrader.Hades.Identity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface IdentityRepository extends JpaRepository<Identity, Integer> {

    List<Identity> findByIdentityType(IdentityType identityType);
}
```

Organization Repository

```
package com.reeftrader.Hades.organization;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Integer> {

    List<Organization> findByOrganizationType(OrganizationType organizationType);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your organizationRepository and identityRepository classes ?

Comment: Added the two repos

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in your repositories, you have specified your ID as an `Integer` but in your entities they are `int`. Try by changing your entity ids to `Integer`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this to work and came to a new error involving my @MapsId fields in OrganizationMembership being named incorrectly which is now resolved.

The new issue however is a "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated" error.

I believe this is happening due to in my save method I am setting the membership to organization before saving the organization itself so there is no "organizationId" field on the membership that is trying to use persistence to save....

Comment: You could move your     


`@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id") private Organization organization;`


and 


`@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private User user;` 


in your `OrganizationMembershipId` instead of `@Column(name = "organization_id") Integer organizationId;` and `@Column(name = "user_id") private Integer userId;`. Also try without using `@MapsId("...")`

Comment: I removed the composite key ID generation and just turned it into generating a new PK(identity generation) on the OrganizationMembership class as a workaround instead of using a composite key. I will give this a try later to see if I can use it instead but moving apartments this weekend so won't get around to trying that for a few days(very busy)